# Deleting Team Project in TFS after moving Source Control items

Tags: tfs, version-control

I have a situation where I have created a new team project and imported source code (with history) into TFS from VSS. The problem is that the team project name is wrong.

I am planning on creating the new (correct) team project and moving source code from $WrongTeamProjectName to $CorrectTeamProjectName.

Will it be safe for me to delete the tfs project covering $WrongTeamProjectName after the move?

Comment: What mechanism are you planning on using to move it from `$/wrongTeamProjectName` to `$/CorrectTeamProjectName` -- are you going to branch it to the new project?

Comment: no, I was planning on just using the move command in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research for you, and what it comes down to is what you consider to be "safe."  All of your files will be intact, but you will lose all history.  The move command is essentially a rename command-- however, because you are going to a new team project, all you'll see for history is the changeset you checked in.

If you keep `$\WrongProjectName`, but lock it down so that no-one can check-out / check-in files, you will at least maintain the history.

There is, unfortunately, no way to rename a TFS project, either.  So that route would be out as well.

If I were making a recommendation, I would suggest that you do the move, but keep the original project in place.  Then, if you turn on the feature that shows you deleted files, you should be able to see the history of the files in the incorrectly named team project.

Comment: Thanks Robaticus - you are correct. The move command invokes a tfs "Rename". I did this from my $wrong.. to $correct and it worked well.

After this, I did a tfsDeleteProject on $wrong. I could still see the history in $correct!! :D however!. Only TFS administrators can see the history :/ the contributors on $correct cannot see history previous to the Rename command :(

Therefore, I am deleting everything out of $correct and re-importing with vssconvert.exe.. 

Thanks, for your help.

Adam